# Integrate google chart in Laravel5.0 with the data from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5, google-visualization

I want to integrate google chart in my laravel5.0 application. The data is in mysql database. As far I've done researching over internet is given bellow

controller part

```
    public function index(){

    $barChart= DB::table('clients')
        ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
        ->get();
    $bar = json_encode($barChart);
    return view('home')
        ->with('bar', $bar);
}
```

If I print $bar , the result is

```
[{"ClientName":"nayeem","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Tusher","Price":1000},
{"ClientName":"Nirjon","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Remon","Price":1000},
{"ClientName":"Navid","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Erfan","Price":1000},
{"ClientName":"Sazzad","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Farin","Price":2000},
{"ClientName":"Arman","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Sohan","Price":1000},
{"ClientName":"romi vai","Price":9000},{"ClientName":"tasif","Price":1000},
{"ClientName":"trina","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Nuru Vai","Price":1000}]
```

view part

```
<div class="panel-body" id="barChart"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$bar?>);
      var options = {
      title: 'My Bar chart',
      is3D: 'true'
   };
   var chart = new  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

But it shows "table has no column" . I know I haven't create any column and I also understand that simply writing this `google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$bar?>)` will not create any column. I've tried many ways to create column but can not find any solution. How can I create data table from this?

I also tried chartWraper

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0');
    function drawInventoryChart() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            dataTable: [], //don't know how to put $bar here
            option: {title: 'test'}
        });
        wrapper.draw('barChart');
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawInventoryChart);
</script>
```

This also does not work as I can not properly have the value of `dataTable[]` .

Comment: Is your `$bar` data in the correct format for the Google Charts package to interpret?

Comment: no, it is not. That is why $bar is not working and I don't know how to make it compatible with with google chart format.

Comment: @WhiteHat I added the value of $bar in my question as you asked. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array.forEach` to load the data into the data table.

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    // use the following
    //var sqlData = <?=$bar?>;

    // for example
    var sqlData = [
      {"ClientName":"nayeem","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Tusher","Price":1000},
      {"ClientName":"Nirjon","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Remon","Price":1000},
      {"ClientName":"Navid","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Erfan","Price":1000},
      {"ClientName":"Sazzad","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Farin","Price":2000},
      {"ClientName":"Arman","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Sohan","Price":1000},
      {"ClientName":"romi vai","Price":9000},{"ClientName":"tasif","Price":1000},
      {"ClientName":"trina","Price":1000},{"ClientName":"Nuru Vai","Price":1000}
    ];

    // create data table
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Client');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Price');

    // load data table
    sqlData.forEach(function(row) {
      data.addRow([row.ClientName, row.Price]);
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'My Bar chart',
      is3D: 'true'
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barChart"></div>
```

Comment: also note I'm using `loader.js` which is recommended versus `jsapi`, see [Load the Libraries...](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs)